# How to append the download status of a file using node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm able to download a file.But I want to find the download status of a file i.e,whether the download is complete (or) how much % it is completed.

Can anyone please help me out on this issue ...

My index.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');


var download = function(uri, filename, callback){
  request.head(uri, function(err, res, body){
    console.log('content-type:', res.headers['content-type']);
    console.log('content-length:', res.headers['content-length']);

    request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
  });
};


download('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png', 'google.png', function(){
  console.log('done');
});



module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen this node package before?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-progress

You use it together with request to report on progress like so:

```
var request = require('request');
var progress = require('request-progress');

// Note that the options argument is optional 
progress(request('http://google.com/doodle.png'), {
    throttle: 2000,  // Throttle the progress event to 2000ms, defaults to 1000ms 
    delay: 1000      // Only start to emit after 1000ms delay, defaults to 0ms 
})
.on('progress', function (state) {
    console.log('received size in bytes', state.received);
    // The properties bellow can be null if response does not contain 
    // the content-length header 
    console.log('total size in bytes', state.total);
    console.log('percent', state.percent);
})
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('doodle.png'))
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Through the above code,I'm able to download a file.But I'm unable to see the received size in bytes,total size in bytes,percent on the console

Comment: Did you have a look at the examples on the Github repo?

Comment: yes.I've made throttle and delay to zero.And now I'm able to get all the parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur help sir.Can you please check the below url and give the suggestions  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33686901/how-to-add-the-download-status-of-a-file-to-a-datatable-using-node-js